# Google Analytics - www version and non-www version

Tags: domains, google-analytics, no-www

We have been using **Google Analytics** for a site `http://example.com` (**non-www version**). In a recent update, we have moved the site to `http://www.example.com` (**www-version**) with a 301 redirect from the non-www version.

Does this mean a **New Analytics Code** should be obtained from Google for the www-version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should edit your [existing profile to use the www version](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=750ad3260fec43a5&hl=en), so that you don't lose your current stats.
2. Redirects from the [old version of the domain will still be counted](http://www.google.ru/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=31597eaceabf06b0&hl=en).